# How do I neutralize melter honey?

Tags: honey

I was wondering how to neutralize melter honey into more of a straight sugar base and get the acid levels down.

Answer (score 1):

Melter honey is melted and extracted from the caps of the honey comb. The prolonged heating can caramelize the sugars a bit and darken the honey.

Although it may reduce a little, I'm not able to find any resource that says that it reduces enough to become significantly more acidic than regular honey.

Regular honey can be neutralized for cooking by adding 1/2 tsp of baking soda for every cup of honey that is used. I think this ratio would also be appropriate for melter honey.